# Child theme - Overriding 'require_once' in functions.php

Tags: functions, themes, child-theme, parent-theme

I am attempting to modify a wordpress theme with a child theme. My parent theme has the following function in its functions.php:

```
require_once(get_template_directory() . "/includes/theme-styles.php");
```

I would like to change this to include my own stylesheet: something like:

```
require_once(get_template_directory() . "../child-theme/includes/theme-styles.php");
```

I can include this function in my child theme's functions.php, but
because the child theme's functions.php is loaded first, I see no way to override/prevent the parent theme's require_once() from being called. Is there any way to do this, or a possible workaround?
Thanks

Comment: What is in `theme-styles.php`

Comment: @PieterGoosen theme-styles.php contains custom css/scripts for the theme that are loaded via 'require_once()' in functions.php

Comment: If you don't include that file, you will probably miss some style files that you need. It's best to include you own style.css file along with the parent theme stylesheets.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `get_stylesheet_directory()` to refer to your child theme, then you can point to your file.

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/theme-styles.php' );
```

It will load your file and replace the parent theme file.